# How to access a related table field from a Controller?

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, find, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to get an array structure of a database and a few of its fields from my controller.
The fields I want are: Document.id, Document.name, Document.submission_date, and the Requester.name which is joined with: Requester.id = Document.requester_id

In my Controller:

Method A:

```
$documents = $this->Document->find('list', array('fields' => array('Document.name', 'Requester.name', 'Document.submission_date')));
```

Can't seem to find 'Requester.name'

Method B:

```
$documents = $this->Document->find('list', array('fields' => array('Document.name', 'Requester.name', 'Document.submission_date'), 'recursive' => 0));
```

Gives me:

```
    array(
        '2012-08-17' => array(
            'Document_A' => 'Requester_Z'
        ),
        '2012-08-05' => array(
            'Document_B' => 'Requester_Y'
        ),
        '2012-07-09' => array(
            'Document_C' => 'Requester_X'
        )
    )
```

But I need it to be in format:

```
    array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '16'
            'submission_date' => '2012-08-17'
            'name' => 'Document_A',
            'requester_name' => 'Requester_Z'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '41'
            'submission_date' => '2012-08-05'
            'name' => 'Document_B',
            'requester_name' => 'Requester_Y'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '213'       
            'submission_date' => '2012-07-09'
            'name' => 'Document_C',
            'requester_name' => 'Requester_X'
        ),
    )
```

I can't seem to figure it out after going through the 2.0 CakeBook and on StackOverflow...
Any help would be appreciated?  Sorry - I'm still a n00b with CakePHP (but REALLY loving it so far!)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a `find('all')` instead of a `find('list')` and you can use the `fields` key like you already are to limit the amount of info that's returned.

It won't come back exactly as you need the data, each field will be in a key of the model it belongs to - if you really need it in that format you can get away with using a virtual field, a custom find, or an afterFind callback to modify the data.

Find list is generally for an `id => label` formatted array.

Comment: Actually, the keys CAN be (might even be preferred) the id field.  In that case, what'd work better?

Comment: Also, I tried
    $documents = $this->Document->find('all', array('fields' => array('Document.name', 'Requester.name', 'Document.submission_date')));

And $documents is NULL - I can't figure out why...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$documents = $this
                ->Document-
                >find('all', 
                        array(
                            'fields' => array('Document.name', 'Requester.name', 'Document.submission_date'),
                            'joins' => array(
                                'table' => 'requesters',
                                'alias' => 'Requester',
                                'type' => 'left',
                                'conditions' => array('Requester.id = Document.requester_id')
                            )
                        )   
                    );
```